# My receipt is Faded

Tags: address

Basically after purchasing my bitcoin from atm machines i put receipt in wallet by the time I went to use it some of the  the receipt was faded to were i can't read it and it won't even scan. What do I do?

Comment: I think you should contact ATM support. If the key faded to the point of being unreadable this board won't be a help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=reading+faded+receipts

Answer (score 0):

In a way, you missed due diligence.

If I understand you correctly, you were using some kind of paper wallet scheme.

You should have created some copies of the paper wallet and properly replace them for new ones as they aged.

Or use a different way of key management. Each way comes at their different risks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cryptocurrency wallet that you used to receive the Bitcoin from the ATM, check the wallet's transaction history. If the transaction was successful, you should see the incoming transaction in your wallet's transaction list. This will show the public address where the Bitcoin was sent.Or think back to when you made the purchase. Consider if you still have any other related documents, such as receipts from the time of the transaction or any notes you might have made.

Comment: I think the main point of the question is that many Bitcoin ATMs print a private key on the receipt that the buyer needs to use to sweep the funds into their wallet. So the question is not about finding where the funds went but accessing the funds in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I apologize for the misunderstanding. You are right; Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try viewing the receipt under different lighting. Or take a clear, high-resolution photo of the faded receipt and use image editing software to adjust brightness, contrast, and other settings. I hope this helps.